# Weka and Python Random Forest different results

Tags: python, scikit-learn, weka

I'm using Random Forest classifier in scikit learn, but the performance I get is at least 3% lower than what I get when I use Weka, I have tried to set and adjust the parameters of  RF in python to be the same as weka but didn't help.
 here is the page for weka default parameters for RF:
http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/trees/RandomForest.html

and I did the same for python in which I set:
 n_estimators = 100

Others left the same because they are the same as in default settings for python.

However, I'm not sure about these two settings:

-V

-I 
  Number of iterations.

what is their equivalent in python? or if this could be to other optimization done in Weka?

I'm using 10 fold cv.

Thanks,

Comment: Random forests have different implementations, and, in general, are randomized algorithms. If you look at the docs, there are zillions of tiny knobs to configure in the sklearn version.

Comment: @Ami Tavory what could give me the optimal performance for RF in python, I have also tried some to adjust other params in python following this https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/06/tuning-random-forest-model/ but it is always lower than in weka

Comment: Try [tuning parameters through CV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/grid_search_digits.html).